# Grey Out Sold Out products

Tags: out-of-stock

Is there a way to grey out the picture of items that are sold out? or does it exist in any magento connect extensions?

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to add an extra class to the product image of the sold out product then you can solve it with pure CSS.

Check: https://gist.github.com/karlhorky/3478370